# Canon M50 Firmware buggy?

Tags: canon

I upgraded to the Canon M50 firmware 1.0.2 two weeks ago.

Since yesterday, here are what challenges I'm facing:

- Can't switch from Manual or any other mode to Video mode.
- Video mode
  is activated only when mode dial is set to Video before flipping
  power on
- Other than main start/stop recording button on top, no other
  button works, literally. Pressing any of the buttons does not work.
  Only on/off and shutter/start/record buttons work. Thus, I can't even
  get to menu to go settings and reset the device

Recording and picture taking also are locked at the last set settings I used, because I can't change anything.

Screentouch doesn't work. Buttons don't work. Camera almost like a brick point and shoot camera.

I am hoping to downgrade to the 1.0.1 and see if there'll be any difference. Except, I can't even get to the Menu to apply the firmware.

Is this something of a software bug? Or is it hardware related?

Camera hasn't fallen or hit anything.

Will appreciate any hints or workarounds.

Comment: Since DuckDuckGo-ing `EOS M50 firmware problems` & `eos m50 buttons do not respond` do not bring up anything, I would bet on either a faulty firmware flash or a hardware defect. IIRC, you can also flash the firmware via EOS utility on your computer - you might want to try that. **Oh, and backup your images from the cam's SD-card ASAP!**

Comment: @flolilolilo good to know about the EOS utility. Will try that. Thanks.

Comment: @flolilolilo I downgraded and upgraded. Issues persist. At this point I think it's a hardware malfunction, albeit a very very weird one.

Comment: Did it ever have contact with salt water?

Comment: @flolilolilo Not really, unless taking it close to the sea-side counts as contact with salt water. To the best of my knowledge, no kind of water i.e salt water or any other kind, has come in contact with the camera. Not even a single drop of water has touched this camera since I bought it, literally

Comment: After struggling with these challenges, I don't want to believe it's a hardware failure. The behavior is a reflection of a buggy software. If the hardware is malfunctioning, the behavior would be consistent. For example, although I could update firmware using the EOS utility, now I can't. It only says "Busy" and the utility freezes.

Comment: Mh, that could just as well be a corroded/loose/... lane on the PCB. Software faults tend to be reproducable (e.g. only M mode does not work) and tend to happen to most users, so we should find something in the internet about this. Granted, I cannot rule out the possibility, but it seems highly unlikely to me.