# Physical button reset Canon M50

Tags: canon

I want to know if there's a physical button somewhere on the Canon M50 to reset the device, like many routers have.

This is now critical for me, because of my [previous question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105565/canon-m50-firmware-buggy), where many of the buttons on the camera no longer work.

I can't use the buttons, which means whatever resetting instructions the internet keeps throwing at me is useless.

Also, I can't communicate with the camera via cable in the EOS Utility on PC although the utility detects the camera and opens itself up. However, any attempt to communicate with the camera, the response I get is "Busy", and either nothing happens, or the utility software freezes.

Thus, is there a physical button somewhere to reset the camera?

I can't see any, but asking, perhaps there's somewhere I'm not looking.

Comment: Have you tried removing the battery for an extended period, like 24-48 hours?

Comment: @Michael C as unexpected as I was, taking the camera out even for about 8 hours, now everything is back to normal. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear! I modified my answer but I still think that a short "Pulling out the battery helped!" would be the best answer to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the battery for 24-48 hours. This will allow some of the capacitors in the camera that provide energy to preserve certain things, such as time and date - but also other settings as well, to discharge. You'll probably need to reset the time/date if it works.

From a comment by the OP:

> As unexpected as I was, taking the camera out even for about 8 hours, now everything is back to normal. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep this troubleshooting 101 in mind for next time. Now when not in use, I just remove the battery. Even for days the camera time/date still works.

Answer (score 3):

This is not saying much, but it would be the first time that I had seen a dedicated hardware reset button on a camera.

[The M50's manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/3/0300029803/01/eosm50-um-en.pdf#page=52) does not list any hardware reset button in the nomenclature (pp. 52), but on p. 298 "Restoring Default Camera Settings" it states that you can reset it via:

> 1. Access the menu's `SET UP 5` screen (<kbd>MENU</kbd> >> 5<sup>th</sup> menu of the wrench-tab (yellow))
> 2. Press `Clear settings`
> 3. Press `Clear all camera settings` >> Press `OK`

Given the fact that you seem to have tried that, I do not think that there is anything you can do without opening the camera (or at least having some kind of servicing software). For a "proper" hardware reset, the least you would have to do is to disconnect the camera's own battery <sup>Used to keep the time while the battery pack is in your charger</sup>, but the manual does not tell us where this is located (and if it is even possible to disconnect it) either.

**[Michael's comment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105777/physical-button-reset-canon-m50/105782#comment202274_105777) on removing the main battery for 24-48 hours might be a last tip that could work**, <s>but again, I assume that you have already tried that.</s>

In most cases, I assume that internet "hacks" are anecdotal at best - and dangerous at worst. E.g. taking out the battery while the camera is doing an exposure *probably* will not harm the camera - but it might well damage your SD card (well, at least it might corrupt its file system).

---

<s>I fear that either way, you will have to bring it to some kind of repair service, or, if applicable, RMA it.</s>

Comment: I do not know the Canon, but most cameras will do an exposure (but overwrite it as soon as another exposure happens) without any card installed? Alternatively, use some old junk 128MB card or something....

Comment: @rackandboneman Yes, you can allow Canon cameras to do an exposure even without a card (I think it is the default setting, even) - it will not be saved. My point was: If you try it and you have forgotten to pull your card out, then you might have a problem.